# Variable not rendering in {{ }} but only in ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm facing a problem in AngularJS and I'm not able to solve it.

I have a simple search bar in my html code :

```
<html ng-app="webApp">
<body>
<div class="row" ng-controller="IndexController">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">
            <form>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_input" placeholder="Search for..." ng-model="search">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="research()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
            Search : {{search}}
            <span ng-bind="search"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./static/javascripts/angular/angular.module.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="./static/javascripts/angular/controllers/index.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

My module is declared in an external file :

```
angular.module('webApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'elasticsearch', 'angular-highlight']);
```

I have a simple controller which is binding the value from a search bar :

```
angular.module('webApp').controller('IndexController', IndexController);

function IndexController($scope, $window, $http) {
$scope.search = '';

$scope.research = function(){
    console.log($scope.search);
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:4000/results?search=" + $scope.search + "&size=20";
};
}
```

So my problem is that I my variable search is well rendered in the ng-bind directive but not at all between {{ }}. I have no errors in my console.
Would you have an idea why ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr?

Comment: it works fine for me, see this [plunkr](http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/sd03ku99/) where I am using your code exactly as you provided it

Comment: I don't see any problem

Comment: Code seems straight forward..It wont work only if you had `Search : {{search}}` inside `ng-if` element

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the problem. As is, the app wouldn't start due to missing modules. Also, Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem in a plunkr, unfortunately.. The only difference I have with plunkr shared by @Jax is that my html page is rendered by the Flask framework in Python, which is my back-end .. That is the only reason I can find ....

Comment: Have you inspected the source code of the HTML in the browser? Does it have `{{search}}` inside? I don't know anything about Flask, but maybe the double mustaches mean something to Flask, and it replaces them with something else.

Comment: And indeed, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#rendering-templates shows that double mustaches mean something to Flask.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JBNizet, indeed the {{ }} in Flask has a different meaning. I'm going to post the solution for the people having the same trouble

Comment: The solution is to use : 

{% raw %}
{{search}}
{% endraw %}

whenever you need to use angular tags in Flask html pages.

Thanks a lot JB Nizet !!

Comment: Or you could configure the angular interpolation provider to use something other than mustaches

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of "scope soup". Since you are passing modules into your application, there is a possibility of an non-aliased controller having the same $scope.search variable. I recommend aliasing your controller on the markup [ex. IndexController as IndexCtrl] and in the controller change $scope to a this reference.

Example:

```
var vm = this; //preference

this.search = '';

this.research = function(){
    console.log(vm.search);
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:4000/results?search=" + vm.search + "&size=20";
};
```

Additionally, you would then reference the search variable in your markup like this:

```
search: {{IndexCtrl.search}}
```

Depending on you intent, you may also want to inject the $location service into your controller and replace *window.location.href(...)* with *$location.path(...)*

Remember that ngBind is for one-way binding where as ngModel is for two-way binding!